# Ui-grid: Opening a modal in filterHeaderTemplate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-grid

I would like to have a filter that would be a very basic kind of a modal window opened on a click event.
However, I am unable to display that window on top of a grid, when it is located in filterHeaderTemplate.

I created a very simple Plunker to reproduce that issue - the div is created correctly but it's hidden below the ui-grid and it happens for any z-index.

http://plnkr.co/edit/15oUIui2kWfPgE5CQXwk?p=preview

The templates is as simple as that:

```
<button ng-click="showModal = !showModal">Open \'Modal\'</button>
<div class="myModalClass" ng-if="showModal">My \'Modal\' Content</div>
```

and styles for the modal:

```
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background-color: white;
border: 3px solid black;
position: absolute;
z-index: 999999999;
```

Any ideas would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Solved :)
The problem was connected with top-panel and header-viewport overflow that is set to hidden by default.

The possible solution is to set it to visible:

```
.ui-grid-top-panel,
.ui-grid-header-viewport {
   overflow: visible !important;
}
```